# Finding "duplicate" rows that differ in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, duplicate-data

I have a table like the following in MySQL 5.1:

```
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| log_id       | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date         | datetime       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date_millis  | int(3)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eib_address  | varchar(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address   | varchar(15)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value        | decimal(20,10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| application  | tinyint(4)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phys_address | varchar(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| orig_log_id  | bigint(20)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In this table, `log_id` and `orig_log_id` are always unique.  It is possible that two rows may have duplicate values for any of the other fields, though.  Ignoring the `*log_id` fields, our problem is that two rows may be identical in all other columns, but have differing values for `value`.  I am trying to figure out the correct SQL query to identify when two (or more) rows have identical values for `date`, `date_millis` and `eib_address`, but different values for `value`, `log_id` and `orig_log_id`.  So far, I've been able to come up with a query that accomplishes the first clause in my previous sentence:

```
SELECT main.* 
FROM sensors_log main
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT date, date_millis, eib_address 
    FROM sensors_log 
    GROUP BY date, date_millis, eib_address 
    HAVING count(eib_address) > 1) dupes 
ON main.date = dupes.date 
    AND main.date_millis = dupes.date_millis 
    AND main.eib_address = dupes.eib_address;
```

However, I can't seem to figure out when `value` differs.  I at least know that just throwing `AND main.value != dupes.value` into the `ON` clause doesn't do it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's a bit simpler than you're trying to make it.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SENSORS_LOG s1
  INNER JOIN SENSORS_LOG s2
    ON (s2.DATE = s1.DATE AND
        s2.DATE_MILLIS = s1.DATE_MILLIS AND
        s2.EIB_ADDRESS = s1.EIB_ADDRESS)
  WHERE s1.VALUE <> s2.VALUE OR
        s1.LOG_ID <> s2.LOG_ID OR
        s1.ORIG_LOG_ID <> s2.ORIG_LOG_ID;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This is more or less what I need.  I'd rather not have the full contents of both tables, but it'll do the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: That makes it so simple! Just what I was looking for, as well.  I obviously selected only the columns I cared about, but the universality is great in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I mistook the problem, but can't you just perform a `COUNT` like this?

```
SELECT date, date_millis, eib_address, count(*) as nr_dupes
FROM sensors_log
GROUP BY date, date_millis, eib_address
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

or

```
SELECT date, date_millis, eib_address, 
       group_concat(value), group_concat(log_id), group_concat(orig_log_id)
FROM sensors_log
GROUP BY date, date_millis, eib_address
HAVING count(*) > 1
```